# Getting error - Service 'web' failed to build : manifest for node:12.18.3-apline not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to build a docker-compose.yml file but I am recieving the following error when I attempt to build this. I am new to docker so it maybe something simple:

```
Building web
Step 1/7 : FROM node:12.18.3-apline
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : manifest for node:12.18.3-apline not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
# web builds from dockerfile in current dir
web:
build: .
ports:
  - "5002:5002"
cap_add:
  - DAC_READ_SEARCH
  - SYS_ADMIN
environment:
  DB_B2_HOST: *****
  DB_B2_PASS: *****
  DB_B2_USER: *****
security_opt:
- apparmor:unconfined
stdin_open: true
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12.18.3-apline

ARG NPM_TOKEN

COPY . /var/www

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apk add --no-cache bash && \
    echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}" > ~/.npmrc && \
npm install && \
rm ~/.npmrc

RUN chmod +x /var/www/start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: I did not find your node tag 12.18.3-apline https://hub.docker.com/_/node?tab=description&name=alpine

Answer (score 1):

I spelt alpine wrong, problem is now solved!